# Question about the Dyson-Schwinger equation for 4-point function of the SYK model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, spin-models, majorana-fermions, large-n

In studying the SYK model, I have no idea how to get the **kernel** $K(t_a,t_b,t_3,t_4)$ and $\Gamma_0(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)$ and also ladder diagrams in the Dyson-Schwinger equation for 4 point function of the **SYK model**. Can anyone shed some light on this?
[[image: Kernel, <span class=]$\Gamma_0$ and ladder diagrams ">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJbND.jpg)

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Is the problem that you do you not know the Feynman rules for the Sachdev-Ye-Kitaev (SYK) model?

Comment: I can't derivation the Feynman rules for the SYK model.  Can you please help understanding this derivation?

Comment: this: [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06768) paper. The key ingredient here is conformal symmetry and that is what Polchinski and Rosenhaus are using. @SethWhitsitt